# Displaying stackOverflow API JSON data using Flask

Tags: python, json, flask, python-requests

I've been trying to display my username and reputation from the JSON data  retrieved from the StackOverflow API.

Im using the python module **Requests** to retrieve the data.
Here is the code

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify
import requests
import simplejson 
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    uri = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users?   order=desc&sort=reputation&inname=fuchida&site=stackoverflow"
    try:
        uResponse = requests.get(uri)
    except requests.ConnectionError:
       return "Connection Error"  
    Jresponse = uResponse.text
    return Jresponse

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

The unused imports is what I need to get this done but cant seem to know how to get it done.
Below is what is returned to the browser, I want to just display the username [display_name] and the reputation. what options do I have to get this done ?

> {"items":[{"user_id":540028,"user_type":"registered","creation_date":1292207782,"display_name":"Fuchida","profile_image":"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6842025a595825e2de75dfc3058f0bee?d=identicon&r=PG","reputation":13,"reputation_change_day":0,"reputation_change_week":0,"reputation_change_month":0,"reputation_change_quarter":0,"reputation_change_year":0,"age":24,"last_access_date":1332905685,"last_modified_date":1332302766,"is_employee":false,"link":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/540028/fuchida","website_url":"http://blog.Fuchida.me","location":"Minneapolis
>   MN","account_id":258084,"badge_counts":{"gold":0,"silver":0,"bronze":3}}],"quota_remaining":282,"quota_max":300,"has_more":false}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **json.loads()** to read and decode the data.

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify
import requests
import simplejson 
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    uri = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users?   order=desc&sort=reputation&inname=fuchida&site=stackoverflow"
    try:
        uResponse = requests.get(uri)
    except requests.ConnectionError:
       return "Connection Error"  
    Jresponse = uResponse.text
    data = json.loads(Jresponse)

    displayName = data['items'][0]['display_name']# <-- The display name
    reputation = data['items'][0]['reputation']# <-- The reputation

    return Jresponse

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: Thanks ! This resolved the issue for me be it with the below adjustment. It only returns the username but that good enough for now.
Thanks ! This resolved the issue for me be it with the below adjustment. It only returns the username but that good enough for now."""""

_displayName = parsedData['items'][0]['display_name']_
_return displayName_